# How can I open an external app with a file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question, I can't find the right one online.
I create a file and then want it to be opened by the app that matches the extension. Which should the user decide for himself if necessary. Such as e.g. opening an attachment in a mail.
Unfortunately, I can't find anything how I can persuade the system to do so with dart / flutter.
Can someone please help me.
Many thanks.

Mike

Comment: can you be more specific on that please? I suggest to read https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files as it shows how to read from files ini flutter.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin seems to do what you want

https://pub.dev/packages/open_file

Try to pass file path to open method as pecified in documentation

> OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.txt");